# How to stop running threads when fragment starts?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-asynctask

When my app starts, user is greeted with a `ListView` which contains images. Those images are being downloaded by using `AsyncTask`. If you open that fragment a few times - images keep loading for a long period of item.

As I understand, this is happening because a lot of download `AsyncTasks` are being created and a lot of duplicates images are being downloaded, since `ListView` has been called for a few times in a row.

My question is how to complete stop these running threads when fragments starts up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of stopping them on opening the fragment again, stop them whenever the fragment is destroyed.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    task.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thread's `stop()`, `suspend()` etc., methods have been deprecated, the only way to safely terminate a thread is to have it exit its `run()` method, perhaps via an un-checked exception.

---

The method suggested there is to use a volatile stop flag (blinker in the code below)

```
private volatile Thread blinker;
public void stop() {
    blinker = null;
}
public void run() {
    Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
    while (blinker == thisThread) {
        try {
            thisThread.sleep(interval);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```